# OpenMPI: Host key verification failed on SGE cluster

Tags: openmpi, hpc

I recently installed OpenMPI version 2.0 on my SGE cluster. But when I submit a job I get "Host ket verification failed". Even though I'm able to login to that node(compute10) without the password from the submit host.

The error in the output file:

> Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor). Thus no job control
>   in this shell. Wed Jan 30 15:58:53 EST 2019 **Host key verification**
>   failed. [file orca_main/gtoint.cpp, line 137]: ORCA finished by error
>   termination in ORCA_GTOInt

My SGE script is below:

> !/bin/tcsh
>
> $ -q sge-queue@compute10
>
> $ -pe mpi 8
>
> $ -V
>
> $ -cwd
>
> $ -j y
>
> $ -l h_vmem=64G
>
> date
>
> setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 8
>
> /home/user/orca_4_0_1_2_linux_x86-64_openmpi202/orca ccl3.inp >
>   ccl3.out
>
> date

And my parallel environment *mpi*:

> pe_name            mpi
>
> slots              999
>
> user_lists         NONE
>
> xuser_lists        NONE
>
> start_proc_args    /export/sge6.2_U7/mpi/startmpi.sh -catch_rsh 
>   $pe_hostfile
>
> stop_proc_args     /export/sge6.2_U7/mpi/stopmpi.sh
>
> allocation_rule    $pe_slots
>
> control_slaves     TRUE
>
> job_is_first_task  FALSE
>
> urgency_slots      min
>
> accounting_summary TRUE

Comment: you have to be able to SSH password-less between nodes, and not only from the submit node to the compute node(s)

Comment: I'm able to SSH password-less between nodes. But I still get "Host key verification failed error".

Comment: what is in ` [file orca_main/gtoint.cpp, line 137]` ? it seems the error message is indeed coming from the application and not from `mpirun`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various things, updating OpenMPI to 3.1.0 version and building with the options below solved the issue.

> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-sge
>   --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default